# Javascript Date Equation Issue

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on a webpage where it will show today's date and a beer style to go along with the day of the month. However, neither are showing up and I am not sure as to why. Javascript seems to give me issues everytime I try to use it and I know someone on here can give me a hand. Thanks.

HTML Code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- The Homebrewery - About
    Author: Chris Stastny
    Date: October 15th, 2015
-->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The Homebrewery - About Homebrewing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="About Homebrewing">
  <meta name="author" content="Chris Stastny">
  <link href="final.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<header>    
<h1>The Homebrewery</h1>
    <div id="dateBox">
        Today is <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
           document.write(showDate());
        </script>
        <br />      
        Beer style today <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
           document.write(showBeerStyle(dayNumber()));
        </script>   
     </div>   

</header>
```

Javascript Code

```
var style = new Array();
   style[1] = "Munich Helles";
   style[2] = "Robust Porter";
   style[3] = "American Wheat Beer";
   style[4] = "American Wild Ale";
   style[5] = "German Pilsner";
   style[7] = "Czech Pilsner";
   style[8] = "India Pale Ale";
   style[9] = "English Brown Porter";
   style[10] = "Kolsch";
   style[11] = "Altbier";
   style[12] = "Vienna Lager";
   style[13] = "Baltic Porter";
   style[14] = "Weissbier";
   style[15] = "Oatmeal Stout";
   style[16] = "Saison";
   style[17] = "Belgian Dark Strong Ale";
   style[18] = "California Common";
   style[19] = "Russian Imperial Stout";
   style[20] = "Belgian Dubbel";
   style[21] = "Cream Ale";
   style[22] = "English Brown Ale";
   style[23] = "Doppelbock";
   style[24] = "Rauchbier";
   style[25] = "Lambic";
   style[26] = "Gose";
   style[27] = "Gueze";
   style[28] = "Marzen";
   style[29] = "Scwarzbier";
   style[30] = "Pale Ale";
   style[31] = "Irish Stout";

function showDate() {
   thisDate = new Date();
   var thisWDay=thisDate.getDay();
   var thisDay=thisDate.getDate();
   var thisMonth=thisDate.getMonth();
   var thisYear=thisDate.getFullYear();
   var mName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
   "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November", "December");
   var wdName = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
   "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
   return wdName[thisWDay]+", "+mName[thisMonth]+" "+thisDay+", "+thisYear;
}

function dayNumber() {
   thisDate = new Date();
   var leapYearDate = thisDate.setFullYear(2004);
   var baseDate = new Date("January 1, 2004");
   days = Math.floor((leapYearDate - baseDate)/(1000*60*60*24)+1);
   return days;
}

function showBeerStyle(day) {
   return style[day];
}
```

Comment: Please point out where you are getting error.

Comment: I am getting the error with the document.write(showDate)); and the document.write(showBeerStyle(dayNumber())); not showing up with a date or beer style. It just shows up with Today is and Beer Style Today.

Comment: Check the console, any errors?

Comment: Did you try your `dayNumber` function?  For me, it returns `308`.  Which is obviously larger than your array.  It's not clear what you're doing in that function anyway.  You probably just want to simply return `new Date().getDate()`, given the array you showed.

Comment: Do not use `new Date("January 1, 2004")` since parsing of string dates is almost entirely implementation dependent. Use `new Date(2004, 0, 1)`.

Comment: @MattJohnson I tried that and nothing happened.

Comment: The code is verbose. here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qw9v625j/

Comment: Voting to close as the issue can't be replicated. There's an issue with how *showBeerStyle* is used, but the code itself functions.

Comment: @RAdio—there's no point in rewriting the code unless that indicates an error somewhere. Certainly the code can be much more concise, but that doesn't help fix the OP's (undefined) problem.

Comment: My response was not an answer, otherwise I would have answered. It was merely a working solution for comparison, using a different write method and complete rejection of the "equation" so as to point out the same mootness with actual evidence.